# Edit element from Queue without removing it

Tags: c++, queue

I am using the queue library from C++ and I need to pick the front element from the queue and edit this element without removing it from the queue. There is any way to do this?
I need to do something like this:

```
queue<int> myQueue;
myQueue.push(1);
myQueue.push(2);
cout << myQueue.front(); // 2
int a = myQueue.front();
a = 3;
cout << myQueue.front(); // 3
```

Obviously this don't work =D. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`front()` returns a reference,

```
int &a = queue.front();

a = 3;
```

Comment: Or just `queue.front() = 3;`